# Html to PDF using MPDF not taking data to next page

Tags: html, pdf, mpdf, page-break

All the data gets squeezed in one page and it is not taking it to next page. I have a table that gets dynamic value and loops to print the value. If I print more than 10 values it squeezes the table and stays on one page. 
I want if there are large data it simply breaks and continue on new page and taking other tables after it to next page.

Main point I am looking for is if the content is not fitting on 1page of pdf it should break it and take the overflowing data table or div to the next page and should not shrink data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

I had a div tag inside which there was the table tag. So I removed the div tag and just used tables.

Comment: Can u please give code that u tried ? also edit question with Code for Problems u faced.

Comment: I am facing same problem can you explain how did you solved it?